# auto loop skip some index array

Tags: c++

I have seen some code like this

```
float MyFloat[30];
for (auto i : { 0, 1, 4, 5, 18, 19, 26, 27 })
    MyFloat[i] = 100.f;
```

does this mean that it only sets the float of the listed index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `i` is going to take on the values in the initialiser list.

Comment: i know what i does, just wasn't sure if this was away to skip the array index 2, 3, 6, 7, 8.....so on

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're cycling over an [**initializer list**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) of integers, i.e. `std::initializer_list<int>`

> A std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when:
>
> - a
>     braced-init-list is used in list-initialization, including
>     function-call list initialization and assignment expressions
> - a
>     braced-init-list is bound to auto, including in a ranged for loop

The elements not in the list will remain uninitialized.